# SSRS hide a textbox / tablix when the results of a dataset is NULL

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to hide 3 textboxes , which form a row in my tablix. (see below)

[image]

For each of the text box, I've put the following formula

```
=IIF((Lookup(Fields!nires.Value,Fields!nires.Value,Fields!nameBigBoss.Value,"BigBoss")) IS NOTHING,TRUE,FALSE)
```

In theory, the formula should hid the boxes when the `BigBoss` field is `NULL`. In theory too, I should have this (see below)

[image]

This is the theory, of course. Reality check done, I have this (see below)

[image]

What should I put in my formula, to have my textboxes only appear when there are results and the rest of the time, disappear like they've never existed? Reading internet , it seems a possible feat but so far, I've never seen it. Still parsing the net for the holy graal. If you have any hints, I'm all ears.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're placing that formula in the Visible property box as an expression, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the hidden expression in the row visibility. Right now it is hiding those textboxes not the row.

Right click the row and goto row visibility and set your expression there.

[image]

[image]

Also, in your hidden expression you can avoid some typing by just writing

```
=ISNOTHING(Lookup(Fields!nires.Value,Fields!nires.Value,Fields!nameBigBoss.Value,"BigBoss"))
```

Instead of

```
=IIF((Lookup(Fields!nires.Value,Fields!nires.Value,Fields!nameBigBoss.Value,"BigBoss")) IS NOTHING,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Comment: Definitely did the trick. Thanks @anup-agrawal, you are a life savior ;)